# How to add more than one image texture in an extruded face

Tags: texturing, uv

I need help with making a detailed textured wall for one of my games, but I'm really struggling with putting more than one texture on a face + they have to merge perfectly when duplicated and put side to side.
These are the image textures I want to add:
[image]

The other texture is a wood texture, but I can't add it because the file is too big, this is what a small portion of it looks like:
[image]

And this is the wall itself:[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than that! Add some images detailing what you want and what problems you're having. Save an image via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender and then add it/them using [these details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to assign two materials to your mesh. One for the wallpaper and another for the wood paneling.

In *Edit* mode, select the faces for the wallpaper, create and select the wallpaper material, and assign the material with the *Assign* button (right side on the first screenshot). Do the same for the wood panels and a second material. For games, it's recommended to use square textures of 512 x 512, 1024 x 1024 (1k), 2k, or 4k sizes (better performance).

Switch to the *UV Editor* workspace and edit the UV maps.
Your wallpaper texture is seamless and tileable. So you just need to make the UV island as wide as the texture is. The pattern will repeat if you duplicate the mesh objects (e.g. with an *Array* modifier).

[image: wallpaper screenshot]

For the wood paneling, have a look at some references like this here. As you can see the wood pattern is not seamless and you can clearly see the grain of the wooden boards. These are also arranged differently, that is, horizontally and vertically.

[image: reference image]

You can mimic this by arranging the UV islands individually. Select the part in the 3d viewport and unwrap them with *Project From View* or *Cube Projection* (<kbd>U</kbd>). Then rotate the island to align the grain of the wooden boards as you like.

[image: wood paneling]

I couldn't figure out exactly what the cut face of the vertical panels looked like, so I rotated them 45°. I guess there are usually no cut faces visible.

Here is a demo scene with your textures:
[image: demo render]

Comment: I could not thank you more @Blunder. You have saved me from hours of research and work. THANK YOU!